# AWS RDS - DB Triggers invoking Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I need to create an RDS Oracle trigger that will invoke a Lambda function when fired. This trigger needs to get the access to invoke the function. The policy AWS_FullLambdaAccess is the right policy for this job. How to attach it to let the trigger get access?

Please refer to this link, especially at very end of the page for DB Account.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html

[image]

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. What do you mean by "DB Service Account"? And when you say that  you "find documentation that says X", what documentation are you referring to (update your post with a link to that documentation)?

Comment: Not clear how your automated job relates to the insert trigger but any IAM principal that needs access to your DB needs to have a IAM policy permitting the relevant rds-db access. What does the Lambda FullAccess Policy have to do with any of this? None of your processes appears to need this. That's the kind of policy you need to manage Lambda functions and to invoke Lambda functions, neither of which your automated job or eventually-triggered Lambda function appear to need. I'd suggest re-reading the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html).

Comment: @jarmod Will rephrase the question. The concept of the Automated job is not needed here. I realized. There will be a table in the DB, upon any insert/update, a trigger will fire. This trigger will invoke the Lambda function. So trigger needs the Lambda invoke access. How to grant the trigger Lambda access (as a DB instance) is what I m trying to figure out.